# perl debug improvement

Tags: perl, debugging

I often need to debug in my Perl program, some of them are very big, and are not started by `perl xxx.pl.`

I have use Python's pdb module, which can set a breakpoint in program by using

```
pdb.set_trace()
```

When execute to the point, program will give out a python interactive shell. Then I can debug. I want to know that is there a such debug module or method in Perl?  I also want to know other debug support in perl and its modules.

Comment: Have you checked out [`perldoc perldebug`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldebug.html)?  If not, do so; if you have, it's probably worth saying so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the Module : [Enbugger](http://search.cpan.org/~jjore/Enbugger-2.013/lib/Enbugger.pod)  --  Enables the debugger at runtime.

which is what was i wanted.

```
CLASS->stop
```

which can stop the running of program and give out a debug shell .

it also can load many type of debugger, by default , it is `perl5db`.
you can specify other debugger such as this powerful one debugger: `Devel::Trepan`

Comment: If there isn't a good reason to point to a particular version of the module, please use a version independent url. [https://metacpan.org/module/Enbugger](https://metacpan.org/module/Enbugger) [http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Enbugger](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Enbugger) [http://p3rl.org/Enbugger](http://p3rl.org/Enbugger)

Answer (score 2):

The equivalent is [`$DB::single = 1`](http://p3rl.org/debug#Debugging-Compile-Time-Statements).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good tutorial for debugging Perl script:

http://www.ehow.com/how_2095026_debug-perl-programs.html

perl -d yourscript.pl

> Set breakpoints using the "b" command in sections of the code you
>   think are broken. Breakpoints tell the debugger to stop debugging when
>   it reaches that line or function. They can be set on lines or
>   functions and can have conditions attached. For example, to set a
>   breakpoint on line 531 with the condition of "$a > 10", you would use
>   the following command: "b 531 $a > 10"
>
> Run the program, using the "r" command. This will run the program
>   until a breakpoint is reached.